# How to get the entire string from from particular index in TCL

Tags: tcl

I want `10576.53012.46344.35174` from string

```
"CompositionClassification|CC000003|01|10576.53012.46344.35174"
```

I have index of last occurrence of `|`, how will i get complete `10576.53012.46344.35174` sub-string from last `|`

Not familiar with TCL, Suggest solution on this :)

Comment: You want the [`string range`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm) command

Comment: Thanks, Got the string using String range

Answer (score 1):

If you know the index of the first character you want, and you want from there to the end, you use:

```
set theSubstring [string range $theString $idx end]
```

However in this case I'd use `split` and `lindex`, since it looks like a simple delimited list:

```
set theSubstring [lindex [split $theString "|"] end]
```